# Mongodb query to match words separated by space

Tags: java, ajax, mongodb, servlets, pattern-matching

I am implementing auto-complete feature using ajax, servlet and mongodb. Right now, I have implemented a logic which seems to be working partially

Example:

In database if i have following products

```
 1. Xbox Amazon
 2. Amazon xyz
```

When user enters `ama`, the result should contain both the products.But I am getting only `Amazon xyz`.

This is the logic I have written in java,

```
        DBCollection products = db.getCollection("Products");
        BasicDBObject dbObj = new BasicDBObject();
        dbObj.put("modelName",  Pattern.compile("^"+request.getParameter("startswith"),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
        DBCursor cursor = products.find(dbObj);
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you want the content removing, I suggest you use the Flag link at the bottom of the post, and ask a moderator what the options are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\b` (word boundary) in place of `^` for your case.

```
dbObj.put("modelName",  Pattern.compile("\\b"+request.getParameter("startswith"),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

This will allow you to search on words that are not `start of the strings` and also does not match strings which contain `ama` as a part (Eg: `Obama` is not returned)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use just the search string as pattern and it will work in this case. The reason why the pattern you created isn't working is that `^` means the string should be starting with the following pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I have already tried that. Problem with not using ^ is, query brings up all the words that matches. Suppose, if type `x` then it displays all the words which contains x in it. I am trying to do  something like this  shopping sites do. Like Best Buy Walmart and others.

Comment: There is no logical difference between bringing up all strings contain "x" and those containing "ama". To avoid looking up all words matching x you should only perform the query when the search string is of a certain size, e.g. three characters.